# How to set properties value in multi-module project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have a multi-module Spring Boot Gradle project. I have properties in each module yml file that point to database: user, pass, url.

It's working solution, but it's difficult to change project database. Every time I want switch database user or url, I must change 10+ yml files.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Can't you add those property files to the models that are actually build and deploy?

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the properties in a class (see here: https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) and inject the class where needed.

Comment: Nice link, thanks! But I can't change code base at this point of project development cycle. I need some trick/plugin forcing gradle take properties from one file to my sub-modules.